# Adjektivdeklination in komplexer Nominalphrase

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, adjective-ending

Mir ist nicht klar, ob es im folgenden Satz *erworbenen* oder *erworbenem* heißen muss.

> Ich erhoffe mir, meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion *erworbenen / erworbenem* Fachwissen optimal einsetzen zu können.

Für eine Erklärung wäre ich dankbar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solchen Fällen hilft es immer, zuerst alle Teile des Satzes wegzuschneiden, die keinen Einfluss auf das eigentliche Problem haben. Auch Umstellungen der Satzteile können helfen.

Ausgangssatz:

> Ich erhoffe mir, meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion *erworbenen / erworbenem* Fachwissen optimal einsetzen zu können.

Man braucht nur den Teil nach dem Komma, diesen Teil kann man zu einem Hauptsatz umformen:

> Ich kann meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion *erworbenen / erworbenem* Fachwissen optimal einsetzen.

Das geht noch einfacher:

> Ich setze meine Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion *erworbenen / erworbene*m Fachwissen ein.

Noch ein Schritt einfacher:

> Irgendetwas passiert mit dem *erworbenen / erworbenem* Fachwissen.

Der Teil ab dem Wort *mit* ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Es besteht aus einer Präposition (*»mit«*) und einem inneren Objekt (alles, was danach kommt). Die Präposition *mit* erzwingt, dass das innere Objekt im Dativ steht. Dass das so ist, erkannt man auch gut am bestimmten Artikel *»dem«* mit dem dieses innere Objekt beginnt.

Das Vorhandensein eines bestimmten Artikels (allgemein: eines [Determinativs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart))) als Teil des Objekt bewirkt, dass Adjektive und Partizipien, die ebenfalls Teil dieses Objekts sind, und als Attribut eines Substantivs fungieren, schwach gebeugt werden müssen:

- starke Beugung (weil es kein Determinativ gibt)

  > **Erworbene** Fähigkeiten sind wertvoll. (Plural, Nominativ)
  > **Erworbenes** Gold sollte man nicht verlieren. (Singular Neutrum, Akkusativ)
  > **Erworbenem** Gold sollte man nicht trauen. (Singular Neutrum, Dativ)
- starke Beugung (weil es einen bestimmten Artikel gibt)

  > Die **erworbenen** Fähigkeiten sind wertvoll.
  > Das **erworbene** Gold sollte man nicht verlieren.
  > Dem **erworbenen** Gold sollte man nicht trauen.

Im vorliegenden Fall haben wir:

- Dativ
- sächlich (Neutrum)
- schwache Beugung (wegen des bestimmten Artikels)

Also genau dieselbe Konstellation wie im Satz *»Dem **erworbenen** Gold sollte man nicht trauen.«*

Was für Gold gilt, gilt auch für Fachwissen:

##### korrekt:

> Irgendetwas passiert mit dem **erworbenen** Fachwissen.

Daher auch korrekt:

> Ich erhoffe mir, meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion **erworbenen** Fachwissen optimal einsetzen zu können.

Die ganze Deklinationstabelle für das Partizip *erworben* gibt es auf [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:erworben#erworben_(Deklination)_(Deutsch))

Answer (score 7):

Es muss heißen

> Ich erhoffe mir, meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit dem in meiner Promotion erworbenen Fachwissen optimal einsetzen zu können.

Man sieht das am leichtesten ein, wenn man nur die relevanten Teile des Satzes betrachtet. Das ist hier die Nominalphrase *mit dem in meiner Promotion erworbenen Fachwissen*. Diese lässt sich vereinfachen zu *mit dem erworbenen Fachwissen*.

Falls das Partizip dem Verständnis  Schwierigkeiten bereitet, kann man es zum Test durch ein einfaches Adjektiv ersetzen: *mit dem grünen Fachwissen*.

Wie [tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20363/tofro) im Kommentar richtig anmerkt, ist die zugrundeliegende Regel hier, dass Adjektive im Dativ mit bestimmtem Artikel schwach gebeugt werden.

Anders sieht es aus, wenn der bestimmte Artikel fehlt. Dann muss der von *mit* geforderte Dativ in der Adjektivendung markiert werden:

> Ich erhoffe mir, meine zuvor in der Industrie erlangten Kenntnisse mit in meiner Promotion erworbenem Fachwissen optimal einsetzen zu können.

Die Analyse geht ganz analog.